# Sub Sub Categories (Суб-Суб категории) WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Необходимо получить доступ к суб-суб категориям.
Таким образом, я получаю категории:

```
$terms = array();
$terms = get_categories(array('orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => 0,'taxonomy' => 'category','parent'  => 0));
if( ! $terms ) return null;
if($first) {
    return $terms[0]->term_id;
}
```

Таким получаю все субкатегории:

```
$parrent_id = array();
    $parrent_id = get_categories( );
    foreach ($parrent_id as $value) {
        $sub_parent_id = $value->parent;
        if($sub_parent_id > 0){
            $sub_parent_id = $value->term_id;
        }
    }
```

Как получить к этим суб-категориям, которые получил скриптом вышe, субкатегории?

Comment: Рекурсия Вам поможет. И букварь:)

Comment: Как реализовать ее с првоеркой на наличие child_of?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На всякий случай с деревом. Не представляю зачем нужны суб суб категории без дерева.

```
#
# каждая нода - ассоциативный массив, представляющий категорию следующим образом:
# 'parent'   => родительская нода
# 'category' => категория
# 'children' => массив нод под-категорий категории category
#
# получается дерево:
# node - category
#   |
#   |- children[0] - (sub)category
#   |    |
#   |    |- children[0][0] - (sub)(sub)category
#   |
#   |- children[1] - (sub)category
#

# рекурсивная функция загрузки категорий, точнее узлов дерева, представляющих категории
# $parent  - и так ясно
# $maxdeep - максимальная глубина, чтобы не грузить лишнего
function get_nodes($parent, $maxdeep) {
    $nodes = [];
    $parent_id = $parent == null ? 0 : $parent['category']->parent;
    $categories = get_categories(['parent' => $parent_id]);
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $node = [
              'parent' => $parent,
            'category' => $category
        ];
        $node['children'] = $maxdeep == 0 ? [] : get_nodes($node, $maxdeep - 1);
        $nodes[] = $node;
    }
    return $nodes;
}

$nodes = get_nodes(null, 3);

# категории
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $category = $node['category'];
    # под-категории
    foreach ($node['children'] as $node) {
        $sub_category = $node['category'];
        # под-под-категории
        foreach ($node['children'] as $node) {
            $sub_sub_category = $node['category']
        }
    }
}
```