# Создание дерева категорий

Tags: php, yii, yii2, рекурсия

Кому-то покажется, что задача обсосанная, но я так вменяемого решения и не нашел, поэтому помогите пожалуйста, чем можете :-)

Итак, есть стандартная таблица category(id, title, parent_id). Parent_id это внешний ключ ссылающийся на id родителя этой же таблицы.

Вытаскиваю с базы все категории одним запросом:

```
$categories = Category::find()->asArray()->all();
```

Массив $categories получается вида:

```
[
    ['id'=>0, 'title'=>'Электроника', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id'=>1, 'title'=>'Компьютеры', 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id'=>2, 'title'=>'ПК', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id'=>3, 'title'=>'Ноутбуки', 'parent_id' => 1],

    ['id'=>4, 'title'=>'Мобильные телефоны', 'parent_id' => 0],


    ['id'=>5, 'title'=>'Бытовая химия', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id'=>6, 'title'=>'Порошок', 'parent_id' => 5],
    ['id'=>7, 'title'=>'Мыло', 'parent_id' => 5],
]
```

и т.д., категории бесконечной (неизвестной) вложенности.

Необходимо из этого массива сделать др. многомерный массив-дерево, в котором дочерние категории вложены в родительские (для последующего древовидного вывода в представлениях). Как это сделать? Какие есть варианты? Спасибо.

Comment: [Набросал код](http://ideone.com/D4YX2e), может быть пригодится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
/**восстанавливает дерево по таблице связей
 * @param $data array
 * @return array
 */
function restore_tree($data)
{
    $lst = prepare_parents($data);

    foreach ($lst as &$parent) {
        restore_tree_impl($parent, $lst);
    }
    return $lst[null];
}

/** восстановление связей родитель->дети
 * @param $parent array
 * @param $data array
 * @return void
 */
function restore_tree_impl(&$parent, &$data) {
    foreach ($parent['child'] as &$child) {
        // Если текущий ребенок сам является родителем
        if (array_key_exists($child['id'], $data)) {
            // восстановить связь
            $child['child'] = $data[$child['id']]['child'];
            // проверить детей
            restore_tree_impl($child, $data);
        } else {
            $child['child'] = [];
        }
    }
}
function make($id) {
    return ['id' => $id, 'title' => '[root]', 'child' => []];
}
/**Создает список узлов, имеющих датей
 * @param $data $data
 * @return array
 */
function prepare_parents($data) {
    $res = [];
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $parent = $item['parent_id'];
        if (!array_key_exists($parent, $res)) {
            $res[$parent] = make($parent);
            if (array_key_exists($parent, $data)) {
                $res[$parent]['title'] = $data[$parent]['title'];
            }
        }
        unset($item['parent_id']);
        array_push($res[$parent]['child'], $item);
    }
    $data = $res;
    return $data;
}

function show($item, $level) {
    if ($item['id'] === null) return;
    while ($level --> 0) {
        echo '..';
    }
    echo $item['title'].PHP_EOL;
}

function print_tree($data, $level = -1) {
    show($data, $level);
    foreach ($data['child'] as $item) {
        print_tree($item, $level + 1);
    }
}

$data = [
    ['id'=>0, 'title'=>'Электроника', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id'=>1, 'title'=>'Компьютеры', 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id'=>2, 'title'=>'ПК', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id'=>3, 'title'=>'Ноутбуки', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id'=>4, 'title'=>'Мобильные телефоны', 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id'=>5, 'title'=>'Бытовая химия', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id'=>6, 'title'=>'Порошок', 'parent_id' => 5],
    ['id'=>7, 'title'=>'Мыло', 'parent_id' => 5],
    ['id'=>8, 'title'=>'Трансформеры', 'parent_id' => 3],
];

$root = restore_tree($data);

print_tree($root);
```

[Результат работы](http://ideone.com/D4YX2e)

Comment: жирновато получилось

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону NestedSetsBehavior (https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets), раз уж используете Yii2.

Comment: Да я в курсе на счет nested-sets, просто нужно было поработать именно с такой таблицей.  Менюшку теперь буду делать именно с помощью nested-sets)

Answer (score 1):

См. сюда [Sub Sub Categories (Суб-Суб категории) WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523198/sub-sub-categories-%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1-%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-wordpress/523287#523287)

Функция `get_categories` схематично

```
function get_categories(parent) {
    if (parent == null) {
        return SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent IS NULL
    } else {
        return SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = :parent
    }
}
```

Как через `Category::find()` понятия не имею, поэтому просто select-ы sql
`maxdeep` убрать, если не нужен.

Можно упростить структуру node, внедрив в них не ссылки на category, а поля этих category. Или в category внедрить ссылку на parent и использовать вместо node.

Answer (score 0):

Вот отличный доработанный вариант этого примера [PHP:Как вывести дерево категорий?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675209/php%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

```
    function CreateTree($array, $sub = 0)
    {
        $arGroup = array();
        foreach($array as $value) {
            if ($sub == $value->parentNodeId) {
                $arGroup[$value->assemblyGroupNodeId] = [
                    'name' => $value->assemblyGroupName,
                    'carId' => $value->carId,
                    'cnt' => $value->cnt
                ];
                $tree = $this->CreateTree($array, $value->assemblyGroupNodeId);
                if ($tree) {
                    $arGroup[$value->assemblyGroupNodeId]['child'] = $tree;
                }
            }
        }
        return $arGroup;
    }
```