# PHP:Как вывести дерево категорий?

Tags: php, mysql, рекурсия

наткнулся на [статью](https://phpdes.com/php/postroenie-dereva-kategorijj-na-php-rekursiya/) хорошо описано про создания дерево категории, но функция вернет ответь в готовый html но я хочу получать дерево в массиве структура такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//Выбираем данные из БД
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  categories");
//Если в базе данных есть записи, формируем массив
if   (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $cats = array();
//В цикле формируем массив разделов, ключом будет id родительской категории, а также массив разделов, ключом будет id категории
    while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $cats_ID[$cat['id']][] = $cat;
        $cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['id']] =  $cat;
    }
}

function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,$only_parent = false){
if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$parent_id])){
    $tree = '<ul>';
    if($only_parent==false){
        foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
            $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
    }elseif(is_numeric($only_parent)){
        $cat = $cats[$parent_id][$only_parent];
        $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
        $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
        $tree .= '</li>';
    }
    $tree .= '</ul>';
}
else return null;
return $tree;
}

echo build_tree($cats,0);//результат в html
```

результат в виде html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: возможно ли получит дерево категории в виде массива не зависимо от вложенности

Comment: Вообще статья не очень. Какой массив вы хотите получить то?

Comment: ну как бы завернуть дерево в массив а не в готовом html, а почему вы считаете что статья не очень возможно вы знаете более легкий красивый код и логики?

Comment: Можно просто ввести левое и правое плечо в базу данных, и level уровень. Выбираете эти данные из базы в одномерный массив с учётом левого и правого плеча. И рендерите одномерный массив на html+css.

Comment: ну в статье мне нравится то что все данные хранятся в одно, и не нужно никакого моста между таблицей, в рекурсии даже меньше кода как мне кажется.

Comment: Это только элюзия, а вообще li формируеться просто введи результирующий массив вместо `$tree` и там `var_dump`. p.s. Рекурсию сложно дебажить к примеру, ` return ` в функции вернёт в выполнение предыдущего вызова функции.

Comment: Можно по этому коду показать а то я делаю так: `$tree = array();` и получаю `null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Вопрос: возможно ли получит дерево категории в виде массива не
>   зависимо от вложенности ?

Отвечаю на этот вопрос во втором примере ! Хотя и первый тоже может понадобится.В моём коде он выводит категории в `dropdown lists(<sleect><option>...)`.

=========================================================================

Примечание : `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` вернёт вам вот такой
 массив:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'name' => 'Раздел 1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'name' => 'Раздел 2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'name' => 'Раздел 3'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Раздел 1.1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Раздел 1.2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'parent_id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Раздел 1.1.1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Раздел 2.1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 8,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Раздел 2.2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 9,
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Раздел 3.1'
    ]
];
```

> Дальнейшие примеры будут приведены исходя из данного массива `$arr`,который может иметь безграничную вложенность иерархий (id -> parent_id ).По крайней мере столько сколько позволено стеков в рекурсии.По моему равен 1000.

**1.Результат: Одномерный массив указывающий глубину вложенности через черточку
    `-`:**

```
function CreateTree($array,$sub=0,$tab='')
{
    //asort($array);
    $category=array();
    if($sub>0){$tab.='-';}
    foreach($array as $v){
        if($sub == $v['parent_id']){
            $category[$v['id']] = $tab.$v['name'];
            $category += CreateTree($array,$v['id'],$tab);
        }
    }
    return $category;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(CreateTree($arr));
```

**2. Результат: Многомерный массив с иерархической вложенностью:**

```
function CreateTree($array,$sub=0)
{
    $a = array();
    foreach($array as $v)
    {
        if($sub == $v['parent_id'])
        {
            $b = CreateTree($array,$v['id']);
            if(!empty($b))
            $a[$v['name']] = $b;
            else
            $a[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(CreateTree($arr));
```

Comment: Ну ваш код даже круче, может добавите "изюминку" в обратную сторону для `хлебных крошек` чтобы вообще как статья вышло =)

Comment: @newprogrammer Ну вот первый чем хуже ? просто вместo минусов подставляйте знак `>`

Comment: для меня именно 2 вариант удобнее так как этот я могу подобрать по ступенькам, все же спасибо за код)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но я малость изменил, чтобы иерархия правильная с чилдами была.
https://paiza.io/projects/s_ZyJPJaDn8A6Po8e2lh2Q

Answer (score 0):

Вывод многоуровневого меню с неограниченным уровнем вложенности

https://webformyself.com/vyvod-mnogourovnevogo-menyu-s-neogranichennym-urovnem-vlozhennosti/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuBaxgzJzd8

Древовидная структура для вывода многоуровневого меню на php

https://webformyself.com/drevovidnaya-struktura-dlya-vyvoda-mnogourovnevogo-menyu-na-php/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0rHzDnwCdQ