# Как достать древо категорий в выпадающий список из БД?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, база-данных

Подключаюсь к БД

```
 require_once 'config.php'; // подключаем скрипт
  // Подключение к базе данных MySQL.
  @$on_link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
  if (!$on_link) {
  echo "Ошибка соединения с сервером MySQL!";
  exit;
  }
// изменение набора символов на utf8
  mysqli_set_charset($on_link, "utf8");
// Выбираем БД для работы в MySQL.

   $db_base_ref =  'vhfffd_1';
  @$db_select = mysqli_select_db ($on_link, $db_base_ref);
    if (!$db_select) {
    echo "Не удалось выбрать БД MySQL.";
    exit;
    }
```

Простой список достаю вот так

```
  <?
 // Делаем выборку из таблицы.
  $sql_cat = "SELECT * FROM `cat`";

  $result_select = mysqli_query($on_link, $sql_cat);

    echo "<select class='row-item-2' name = 'cat'>";

    echo "<option value='0'>Категория</option>";

        while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select)){

            echo "<option value = '$object->id' > $object->name </option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как достать дерево категорий в выпадающий список как на примере внизу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица категорий cat состоит из id, name и parent

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подгружаешь в верхний dropdown те, у которых parent == null, потом далее при выборе подсовываешь parent_id для следующего dropdown

Comment: @SultanovShamil Спасибо за ответ, не могли бы вы показать как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675285/207445
чтобы вывести дерево чего то подобным образом, и особенно если не известна количество вложенности, то тут единственный способ сделать через рекурсию.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan 3 уровня вложенности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-нибудь будет полезно.

```
 <?
    require_once 'config.php';

    // Подключение к базе данных MySQL.
    $on_link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die('Ошибка соединения с сервером MySQL!');

    // изменение набора символов на utf8
    mysqli_set_charset($on_link, "utf8");

    // Выбираем БД для работы в MySQL.
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($on_link, $db_base_ref) or die('Не удалось выбрать БД MySQL.');

    function is_ajax() {
        return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
            && strtolower(getenv('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')) === 'xmlhttprequest')
            || !empty($_REQUEST['ajax']);
    }
    // Получение Категорий из БД
    function get_cat_options($parent, $db) {
        $sql_cat = 'SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `parent` = '. intval($parent) .';';
        $result_select_cat = mysqli_query($db, $sql_cat);
        ob_start();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select_cat)) {?>
            <option value="<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->name?></option>
        <?}
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['cat'])) {
        $subcat1 = get_cat_options($_REQUEST['cat'], $on_link);
        if (is_ajax()) {
            echo $subcat1;
            exit;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['subcat1'])) {
        $subcat2 = get_cat_options($_REQUEST['subcat1'], $on_link);
        if (is_ajax()) {
          echo $subcat2;
          exit;
        }
    }?>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <?// Получение Категорий из БД?>
    <select class="row-item-2" name="cat">
        <option value="0">Категория</option>
        <?=get_cat_options(0, $on_link)?>
    </select>
    <select class="row-item-2 _hide" name="subcat1" style="display:none">
        <option value="0">Подкатегория</option>
        <?!empty($subcat1) ? $subcat1 : ''?>
    </select>
    <select class="row-item-2 _hide" name="subcat2" style="display:none">
        <option value="0">Подкатегория</option>
        <?!empty($subcat2) ? $subcat2 : ''?>
    </select>

    <script>
      function get_cat(from, to) {
        let $t = $('[name="'+ from +'"]'), data = { ajax: 1 };
        data[from] = $t.val();
        $t.siblings('._hide').hide().find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();
        $.get(location.href, data, res => $('[name="'+ to +'"]').append(res).show());
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[name="cat"]').on('change', () => get_cat('cat', 'subcat1'));
        $('[name="subcat1"]').on('change', () => get_cat('subcat1', 'subcat2'));
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Напишите rest api или просто метод, который на вход принимает id категории, и возвращает список подкатегорий этой категории (select * from tbl where parent = param) или сразу html комбобокс с этими данными
- Сделайте страницу, где отображаете комбобокс с корневыми категориями и на onchage вешайте запрос на получение следующих категорий

---

```
$('#root_cat_select').change(
  ()=>{ 
    $.ajax({url: you_service_url, data: {param: $(this).val()}})
   .success(
    (data)=>{$('#you_div_with_selectes').append(data)};
   )
  }
);
```

- Навешайте аналогично на возвращаемые селекты ченжи.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ///////////// Первый селект

   if (1 == 1) {

    $seleras = "SELECT name FROM  `doctype` WHERE `доп поле`= ? ";
    $selectras =  DB::prepare($seleras)->execute(['по умолчанию']);
    foreach ($selectras as $row){
    $rastip=$row[name]; // option селекта
    }

    $s1="$rastip";
    $sk1="$rastip";
    }
    else
    {
    $s1="Выберите тип документа";
    $sk1="";
    }

    // Отправка в GET значения index.php?a='id option1'

    /////////////////   Второй селект  
    if (isset($_GET['a'])) {

    // по значению p формируется запрос

    $seledep = "SELECT depnam FROM  `department` WHERE `доп поле`= ? ";
    $seledeps =  DB::prepare($seledep)->execute([$_GET['a']]);
    foreach ($seledeps as $row){
    $dep=$row[depnam]; // option селекта сформированный от предыдущего селекта
    }

    $s2="$dep";
    $sk2="$dep";
    }
    else
    {
    $s2="Выберите факультет";
    $sk2="";
    }

    // Отправка в GET значения index.php?a='id option1'&b='id option2'    

    ///////////////// третий селект 
    if (isset($_GET['b'])) {

    $selepr = "SELECT nameform FROM  `form` WHERE `доп поле`= ? ";
    $seleprs =  DB::prepare($selepr)->execute([$_GET['b']]);
    foreach ($seleprs as $row){
    $pr=$row[nameform]; // option селекта сформированный от предыдущего селекта
    }

    $s3="$pr";
    $sk3="$pr";
    }
    else
    {
    $s3="Выберите программу";
    $sk3="";
    }

    // Отправка в GET значения index.php?a='id option1'&b='id option2'&c='id option3'  

    /////////////////
```

с помощью JavaQwery манипулируем url страницей и обновлением значений-option всех селектов после каждой отправки очередного GET. 
В базе данных я создал у всех затрагиваемых данных "доп поле" где указывал № селекта и все остальные зависимости, если был выбран в первом селекте оптион №2 то я брал данные из бд для второго селекта у которых в "доп поле" значение 2.

[image: Мой рабочий вариант выглядит так]

При каждом OnChange - JS обновляет страницу добавляя GET который = value-option выбранного в списке значения, php читает GET и если он есть то делает видимый очередной список, который заполняется запросом с WHERE = значение предыдущего списка взятое из GET.

сам урл к концу всех выборок списков примерно такой вот:

```
index.php?mid=17&cid=17&obid=8036&f=g4om8z2i3rv&t=5&p=41&c=2&k=2
```

не очень красивый по этому все GET можно вырезать из урл после выбора последнего списка.

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению структуру БД нарушать не желательно. Может подскажите как реализовать без создания дополнительного поля в БД?

Comment: назначайте при генерации следущего списка "value-оптион=id нужного поля БД"   
<code>     $result="select * from catalog where  "poleDB"= $_GET[а] ";    

foreach ($result as $row){
   $str1.="<option value='.$row[id].'>".$row[name]."</option>";
   }     <code>

Answer (score -2):

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <?php
    if($leftMenu):
        foreach($leftMenu as $menu):
            if($menu['nodeid']==$args[0] or $menu['parentnodeid']==$args[0]) {
                echo '<li class="active">';
            } else {
                if($menu['nodeurl']=='#' and $menu['submenu'][0]['nodeid']>0) {
                    $flag=false;
                    foreach($menu['submenu'] as $menu2){
                        if($menu2['nodeid']==$args[0]){
                            $flag=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if($flag) {
                        echo '<li class="active open">';
                    }else{
                        echo '<li>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<li>';
                }
            }
            if($menu['nodeurl']=='#') {
                if($menu['submenu'][0]['nodeid']>0) {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/'.$menu['nodeurl'].'" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="'.$menu['nodeicon'].'"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text">'.$menu['menuname'].'</span>
                    <b class="arrow icon-angle-down"></b>
                </a>';
                echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                    foreach($menu['submenu'] as $menu2):
                        if($menu2['nodeid']==$args[0]) {
                            echo '<li class="active">';
                        } else {
                            echo '<li>';
                        }
                        echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/'.$menu2['nodeurl'].'">
                            <i class="'.$menu2['nodeicon'].'"></i>
                            '.$menu2['menuname'].'</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</ul>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/'.$menu['nodeurl'].'">
                        <i class="'.$menu['nodeicon'].'"></i>
                        <span class="menu-text">'.$menu['menuname'].'</span>
                    </a>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/'.$menu['nodeurl'].'">
                    <i class="'.$menu['nodeicon'].'"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text">'.$menu['menuname'].'</span>
                </a>';
            }
        echo '</li>';
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/796996/edit), чтобы поправить формат.

Comment: Я думаю этот код не имеет отношение к проблеме.

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить немного комментариев к этой простыне.